# issue with gdata analytics client in python

Tags: python, google-analytics, gdata

I was able to successfully retrieve an OAuth access token for Google Analytics using Google's gdata python library.

However, my attempt to use the token to access Google Analytics data is failing. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
client = gdata.analytics.client.AnalyticsClient(source='myapp')

client.auth_token = access_token # retrieved earlier

dataQuery = gdata.analytics.client.DataFeedQuery({
    'ids': 'ga:********',
    'start-date': '2011-03-23',
    'end-date': '2011-04-04',
    'metrics': 'ga:percentNewVisits',
    'max-results': 50})

data = client.GetDataFeed(dataQuery)
```

I get the following stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py",
>   line 280, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ,
>   self.start_response)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py",
>   line 674, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 248, in **call**
>       response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 141, in get_response
>       return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   resolver, sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 100, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py",
>   line 25, in _wrapped_view
>       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/*********/*****/**/****/*********/googleAnalyticsOauth.py",
>   line 122, in googleAnalyticsTest
>       data = client.GetDataFeed(dataQuery)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/analytics/client.py",
>   line 77, in get_data_feed
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/client.py",
>   line 635, in get_feed
>       **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/client.py",
>   line 265, in request
>       uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token, http_request=http_request, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/atom/client.py",
>   line 110, in request
>       self.auth_token.modify_request(http_request)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/gauth.py",
>   line 980, in modify_request
>       token_secret=self.token_secret, verifier=self.verifier)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/gauth.py",
>   line 604, in generate_hmac_signature
>       next, token, verifier=verifier)
>
> File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gdata/gauth.py",
>   line 565, in build_oauth_base_string
>       urllib.quote(params[key], safe='~')))
>
> File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py",
>   line 1216, in quote
>       res = map(safe_map.**getitem**, s)
>
> TypeError: argument 2 to map() must
>   support iteration

Anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in gauth.py (part of the gdata client library) at about line 587 in version 2.0.15.

The value for the "max-results" parameter being passed to urllib.quote is 10000, an integer, not a string, so it doesn't have an iterator.

My quick hacky fix is:

```
  for key in sorted_keys:
    safe_str_param = urllib.quote(str(params[key]), safe='~')
    pairs.append('%s=%s' % (urllib.quote(key, safe='~'), safe_str_param))
```

You can track down the problem yourself by using pdb, like this:

```
python -m pdb pagination_demo.py
> ga-api-http-samples-read-only/src/data_export/v2/python/pagination/pagination_demo.py(35)<module>()
-> """ """
# Note that (Pdb) indicates a prompt from the debugger
(Pdb) c
Executing query: https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?max-results=10000&...&start-date=2011-01-01&ids=ga%3A999999&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&end-date=2011-12-30

# then you get more or less your trace above, plus this:

TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> lib/python2.6/urllib.py(1224)quote()
-> res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)

# Ok, let's see what the type of 's' is with pretty print
(Pdb) pp type(s)
<type 'int'>
(Pdb) q
```

If everything works (like when you add my hack above to gauth.py), you'll see this instead of the stack trace:

```
Total results found: 124
Total pages needed, with one page per API request: 1

The program finished and will be restarted
> ga-api-http-samples-read-only/src/data_export/v2/python/pagination/pagination_demo.py(35)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb) q
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, one has to do the following:

my_client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET, gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)

[Via](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=473)